# Android inject test dependencies with Dagger: Missing or Conflicting dependencies error

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dagger-2

I want to inject dependencies in android tests using dagger.

I've created a simple App with an AppComponent extending AndroidInjector.
That works for the App itself (the code is built in /build by dagger).

Then, for /test I've also created the AppComponentTest and AppTest.

It took me some time to realised that I need to create a naive test and run it to let gradle create the /build for test.
Now the code is there, but there is some error with that generated code, as you can see here:

[image: AppTest.kt]

[image: DaggerAppComponentTest auto generated]

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**App.kt**

```
open class App : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = dispatchingAndroidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupDagger()
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    open fun setupDagger() {
        DaggerAppComponent
            .factory()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

Then under the same structure but in **/test** I've created this:

**AppComponentTest.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponentTest : AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @BindsInstance application: Application
        ): AppComponentTest
    }
}
```

**AppTest.kt**

```
class AppTest : App() {
    override fun setupDagger() {
        DaggerTestAppComponent
            .factory()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

And this is the **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dagger"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'

    def dagger_version = "2.27"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Also the naive test:
**ExampleUnitTest.kt**

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        assert(true)
    }
}
```

---

I've also tried with other approach using this:
**AppComponentTest2.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [])
interface AppComponentTest2 {
    fun inject(test: ExampleUnitTest2)
}
```

**ExampleUnitTest2.kt**

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class ExampleUnitTest2 {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        DaggerAppComponentTest2
            .builder()
            .build()
            .inject(this)
        assert(true)
    }
}
```

And also the same error:

[image: ExampleUnitTest2.kt]

[image: DaggerAppComponentTest2.kt]

---

Btw, this is a repo with that code:
https://gitlab.com/fitu/dagger

There are two branches there **first_approach** and **second_approach**

---

**EDIT 1:**
I had other repo where I was able to do this injection and now I've tried and it doesn't work.

Comparing dependencies I have:

New project:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61'

implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.27'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.27'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.27'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'

kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
```

Old project:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.70'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.61'
implementation'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'

kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
```

So it seems is not a dagger or kotlin version.

Maybe it's related with Android Studio?

I'm not sure about the version of AS when I'd created that old project, but my current AS version is: 3.6.1

---

**EDIT 2:**
I've deleted almost everything in the project, the main folder with App and everything:
[image: All deleted]

The only reminding was two classes: **AppComponentTest.kt** and **ExampleUnitTest.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [])
interface AppComponentTest
```

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        DaggerAppComponentTest
            .builder()
            .build()

        assert(true)
    }
}
```

The error persist, so I'm guessing the problem could be a combinations of AS version, Kotlin version and/or Dagger version.